# Solidity Ganache/Mocha test error: base fee exceeds gas limit

Tags: solidity, javascript, gas-limit, ganache, mocha

I got this when I was running the Mocha test with Ganache package to test the Solidity smart contracts. Then I got base fee exceeds gas limit error. Is that because my contracts are too large? Should I test each contracts one by one instead? Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the reason is your contract is too complex. You can obviously change the gas limit of block in test env. But it is never recommended to use such complex contracts. You can better break the contract into parts and deploy each contract separately.